# Inventory management system for small biz

Tags: inventory

I'm trying to wade through the myriad of inventory management systems to find something that fits my company but not having much luck. We are a small company with only a few employees so I don't necessarily need something hugely complex or ERP, but I'm willing to spend some money on the right product. I feel like I'm halfway between a warehouse, and halfway between a POS. I receive orders online, and then fill them from inventory. But I'd like to be able to track my supplies from raw materials to completed goods out the door including assembly of the product. This seems to be a big one because most systems seem to focus on receiving completed products (or at least the one's I've seen).  Here is what I'm looking for:

- log incoming raw materials
- convert those raw materials into subassemblies and completed products
  (ie create new product inventory and have raw materials automatically
  deducted) (THIS IS A BIG ONE)
- Fill completed orders.
- be able to print operations reports like cost of goods, total inventory, be able to search old orders.

I feel like this is relatively easy but I feel that second requirement makes things tricky for most systems. So... any recommendations?

I'd prefer windows, bonus points if some of this can be done on a tablet. I'd like for the assembly guys to be able to log in their own products from tablets, but if it needs to be done from a desktop then that's fine too.

Comment: Any OS requirement?

Comment: I'd prefer windows, bonus points if some of this can be done on a tablet. I'd like for the assembly guys to be able to log in their own products from tablets, but if it needs to be done from a desktop then that's fine too.

Comment: Talking about tablet: Android or iOS? In the former case, there's my [list of POS apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory#group_1074) you might wish to take a look at.

Comment: android preferably. I'll take a look at the list.