# Simple(-ish), OSS inventory management/assembly for Linux?

Tags: linux, inventory

I'm looking for something similar to what [this guy](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33938/inventory-management-system-for-small-biz) is looking for, but for Linux, and hosted on an application server (Tomcat, ... - doesn't have to be JavaEE).

We build a lot of equipment for in-house use - like specialised PCs and optical equipment - so we buy in a lot of components and assemble them; it is getting difficult to keep track of which comnponents we have in stock and where they went, once they are used. We need something where we can

- Enter all unused components; scanning isn't really relevant for our use
- Keep track of which build a component was used in
- The application should keep track of suppliers, prices etc
- Database backend, eg. mysql, postgres, ideally via JDBC or ODBC
- No cloud hosting!

Any recommendations? I don't need anything fancy - I could stitch something basic together, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try: [Koillection](https://github.com/koillection/koillection)

- It is open source, and must be self-hosted.
- It can run on Linux. See here for [installation](https://github.com/koillection/koillection/wiki/Installation) requirements.
- Supports Mysql, PostgreSQL, MariaDB.
- It has collections and items management (create, edit, delete).
- Metadata can be added to items etc.
- See [here](https://github.com/koillection/koillection/wiki) for features.